# why does blog page ignore template

Tags: templates, blog

This is never answered completely anywhere.

If there is a dropdown to select what page I want to use for my blog, why would it ignore the template I select? I realize it uses the index. Then why in the world would they a) make you name a page if they ignore it anyway. b)give you an option to chose a template if they ignore it. I read all of the 'it doesn't work that way' posts all over...why the options? If it ignores it why would I select a page to use? Why would it ignore my template?

So I customize the index page. Then there is zero reason for the option. I can pick a front page template but for the blog, they give the options and then just ignore it. Makes no sense. But I can edit the index. Sounds totally stupid.

Comment: "*Sounds totally stupid.*" - Not in the slightest. WordPress reserves a name for the custom template for the Blog Posts Index: **`home.php`**.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [Template Hierarchy Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

The [template hierarchy for the **blog posts index**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display) is as follows:

- `home.php`
- `index.php`

There is no case where the blog posts index will use a page template, either the default page template or a custom page template.

The determination is controlled by [`wp-includes\template-loader.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/template-loader.php). Refer to [**Line 31**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L31):

```
elseif ( is_home()  && $template = get_home_template()   ) :
```

And [`get_home_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_template) is defined in [`wp_includes\template.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/template.php#L0):

```
function get_home_template() {
    $templates = array( 'home.php', 'index.php' );

    return get_query_template( 'home', $templates );
}
```

So, as you can see, the blog posts index never looks for any variation of a page template.

Comment: This is another non-answer. I clearly stated I know your answer. Try reading the question.

Ever looked at an install of WP before? Go to the admin reading page and look at the top. See the cute little dropdown asking for a page for your blog? I guess it is there for fun?

This question is asked all over (as I already said) and nobody has an answer (as I said) so I guess the little cute dropdown is for fun but nothing else? Why in the heck ask for a blog page template if NO SUCH THING EXISTS?

Do I need to attach a picture of the dropdown to prove it exists? Come on!

Comment: You asked, "*why does blog page ignore template?*", and I detailed the template-selection code for the blog posts index. That you don't *like* the answer doesn't mean that it is a "non-answer." "*Try reading the question*"? I recommend rather that you [try reading the WPSE FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#etiquette).

Comment: Nice...refuse to answer because you can not read a simple question. WTF? Can't you simply state why I must select a blog template page that is ignored? Very simple question. Why the dropdown? Telling me the reason the thing works differently in no way addresses my simple question that keeps getting ignored!

Comment: So you simply refuse to answer me because you are arrogant and feel above it? Sorry, I'll go elsewhere to fund someone who can answer a simple question.